# Prevent highlighting text on mousedown

Tags: jquery

I want not to highlight element when I drag some of my element, and for this purpose I did this

```
$('#object')
 .draggable()
 .mousedown(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
 });
```

but now I encounter a problem that my other element's event such as blur didn't invoke.
for instance when the focus enter in the element and this element has blur event, when I chose my draggable element, the blur event of previous element didn't invoke.

How can I handle this. also I didn't know which element focusout that I invoke blur event in mousedown event.

Comment: try CSS...

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)
     `user-select: none;`

Comment: what happanes when you first assign `mosuedown` and after that make your obkect `dragabble`?

Comment: Thanks for help I think I must handle this with css rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#object').css('user-select','none').prop('unselectable','on').on('selectstart',false);
```